# Google drive integration error in ios6 and Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, ios6, google-drive-api, xcode4.5, google-api-objc-client

Guys I am working on integration google drive, i found a code from google-api-objectivec-client in google sdk samples.

I have searched and found that, for resolving these issues you need to add security.framewok and SystemCofiguration.framework , I already do that, but couldn't get success.

Also found that change "Framework search path" to

```
 "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks"
 "$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks"
```

I also do this, but can't short out these errors.

```
 "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:

-[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in   GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:

-[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:

 -[GTMOAuth2Keychain removePasswordForService:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 "_kSecAttrAccessible", referenced from:

 -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

  "_kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly", referenced from:

  +[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch saveParamsToKeychainForName:accessibility:authentication:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:

 +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 "_kSecAttrGeneric", referenced from:

 +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:

 +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 "_kSecClass", referenced from:

 +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:

 +[GTMOAuth2Keychain keychainQueryForService:account:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

"_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:

-[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

"_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:

-[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

"_kSecReturnData", referenced from:

-[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

"_kSecValueData", referenced from:

 -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in  GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o

 Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me, Thanks

Comment: I had the same errors and it turned out I had missed the Security.framework

Answer (score 0):

I'm also face this problem with google gtl framework. According their instruction, initially I've set other linker flag as below

> Add the ObjC linker flag to the app target's build settingss:
>
> Other Linker Flags: -ObjC

After Clear that flags, All warnings gone, got build successfully.

**Note:** I'm using `Xcode5.0`

**Update:** After some time, It will show again same error, but when I try to take build with device, it's gone. But still it appear with simulator.Don't know how to solve it with simulator.